# Difference in explicit and non-explicit C# class initializers

Tags: c#, class, initialization, initializer

What is the resulting difference between these two class initializers? Both seem to be syntactically correct in C#. Is the second one a shortcut for the first?

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1()
{
    Boolean1 = true,
    Class2Instance = new Class2
    {
        Boolean2 = true,
    },
};
```

and

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1()
{
    Boolean1 = true,
    Class2Instance =
    {
        Boolean2 = true,
    },
};
```

I ask because obviously it is not valid to do this:

```
Class1 class1 =
{
    Boolean1 = true,
    Class2Instance = new Class2()
    {
        Boolean2 = true,
    },
};
```

Comment: Class2Instance is of type Class2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two examples you gave are not exactly the same. Using a tool like ILSpy you can check what the complier creates for the two statements.

The first one compiles to something like the following (decompiled using ILSpy):

```
Class1 expr_06 = new Class1();
expr_06.Boolean1 = true;
expr_06.Class2Instance = new Class2
{
    Boolean2 = true
};
```

Whereas the second example compiles to the following (decompiled using ILSpy):

```
Class1 expr_06 = new Class1();
expr_06.Boolean1 = true;
expr_06.Class2Instance.Boolean2 = true;
```

As you can see, in the second example the creation of the `Class2Instance` with the `new`-keyword is missing and you'll get a `NullReferenceException` when running this code.

However, you can prevent getting a `NullReferenceException` in the second example when you create a new `Class2Instance` within the constructor of your `Class1`:

```
class Class1
{
  public Class1()
  {
    Class2Instance = new Class2();
  }
}
```